# Keyboard Shortcut to Swap Mouse Buttons

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, autohotkey, autoit

I use my mouse with both hands and like to switch back and forth for comfort reasons.  However, this is made difficult by needing to go through about a zillion layers of menus to swap the buttons each time.  Is there an easy way to create a single keyboard shortcut that would swap my left and right mouse button?

Edit:  My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 26):

As blsub6 mentioned, you can change a registry value (with a command called from a batch file):

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /t REG_SZ /v SwapMouseButtons /d 1 /f
```

or

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /t REG_SZ /v SwapMouseButtons /d 0 /f
```

**However, you need to logout before it will take effect**.

The **better solution** is to make a tiny .exe with C# to swap the setting, as described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806575/how-do-i-use-rundll32-to-swapmousebutton).

Make a text file which you can call `swapmouse.cs`, containing this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

class SwapMouse
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SwapMouseButton(Int32 bSwap);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int rightButtonIsAlreadyPrimary = SwapMouseButton(1);
        if (rightButtonIsAlreadyPrimary != 0)
        {
            SwapMouseButton(0);  // Make the left mousebutton primary
        }
    }
}
```

And compile it to `swapmouse.exe` with this command:

```
"%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc" swapmouse.cs
```

In more recent versions of .NET you may need to add `/out:swapmouse.exe` and `/target:exe` :

```
"[%SystemRoot%]\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\csc" /out:swapmouse.exe /target:exe swapmouse.cs
```

Then you just double-click that exe to swap the mouse buttons. It takes effect immediately.

Or, as rad mentions, you can create a shortcut, and define a keyboard shortcut/hotkey in the Shortcut tab of it's Properties.

Comment: To start the exe by a **keyboard** shortcut: `1. Right-click on the exe and select "Create Shortcut" 2. Move the shortcut to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" or the desktop 3. Right click on the shortcut, go to the Shorcut tab and select a shortcut key`

Comment: Thank you, works good.

Answer (score 9):

The better AHK code:

```
Run, main.cpl
Send, {Space}{Enter}
```

I also use mouse with both hands and also have Win7, this code works nice!

Comment: This is the best for quicktypers.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 - simply install AutoHotKey and save the above code as an AHK file, double click, and/ or make a shortcut :)

Answer (score 9):

This is the Autohotkey version (modified/based on https://github.com/jNizM/AHK_DllCall_WinAPI/blob/master/src/Mouse%20Input%20Functions/SwapMouseButton.ahk).

```
; autohotkey code - mapped to F12
F12::
    buttonState := DllCall("user32.dll\SwapMouseButton", "UInt", 1)
    if buttonState <> 0
    {
        buttonState := DllCall("user32.dll\SwapMouseButton", "UInt", 0)
    }
```

This works fine with all Windows (including Windows 10).  I usually map it to a hotkey such as "F12" key on my keyboard (using Autohotkey), and I can toggle between left and right mouse button instantly with press of a key.  There's no need to muck with loading Control panel or setting registry / rebooting.

Comment: highly underrated answer. It's the best!

Comment: As of June 2021, it still works great on Windows 10. To avoid losing F12, I used control + alt + m instead. So the first line of code would be this:
^!m::

Answer (score 5):

Here's an app for that: http://code.google.com/p/mouseswap/

If you have [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com) installed, here's the script to run in an au3 file:

```
#NoTrayIcon

HotKeySet("#a","MouseSwap")

Global $Buttons

While 1
   Sleep(50)
WEnd

Func MouseSwap()
   If $Buttons = 0 Then
      DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SwapMouseButton", "int", 1)
      $Buttons = 1
      SplashTextOn("","E8",280,180,-1,-1,33,"Wingdings",80)
      Sleep(600)
      SplashOff()
   Else
      DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SwapMouseButton", "int", 0)
      $Buttons = 0
      SplashTextOn("","8F",280,180,-1,-1,33,"Wingdings",80)
      Sleep(600)
      SplashOff()
   EndIf
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard way of switching mouse buttons on Windows Vista (perhaps 7) and above:

1. Windows Key
2. type "mouse"
3. Spacebar
4. Enter

Yeah, it's 8 key presses but not too bad... I've done it a bunch

Comment: 5. ALT+F4 to close mouse settings window

Answer (score 1):

A C<sup>++</sup> solution is:

```
#include "winuser.h"
int main(){
    if (SwapMouseButton(0) == 0)
        SwapMouseButton(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Create a shortcut to the executable version of this program and place the shortcut in the Start Menu programs folder (`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`), then assign the shortcut any shortcut key you like in its Properties box.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno about a keyboard shortcut but you can make two reg files that do what's described [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/849/swap-the-mouse-buttons-make-your-mouse-left-handed/). Just click and away you go.

If you really want to get nuts with it, set up an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that triggers the reg files

Comment: That’s no good, simply changing the registry entry has no effect; the buttons remain unchanged. You would need to reboot or log out and back in for them to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I like to avoid using random exe files when possible, here is a AutoHotKey solution based on the keyboard solution previously mentioned.

Make a shortcut at called c:\mouse.ink that opens the mouse settings.

Use this AHK script:

```
#a::
Run c:\mouse
sleep 250
send {Space}
Send {Enter}
return
```

Comment: The exe is just a compiled AutoIt script (similar to AutoHotkey). Instead of the exe, you could run the au3.

Answer (score 0):

As mivk mentioned, this is straight forward and working like a charm. This is what mivk mentioned

Make a text file which you can call swapmouse.cs, containing this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

class SwapMouse
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SwapMouseButton(Int32 bSwap);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int rightButtonIsAlreadyPrimary = SwapMouseButton(1);
        if (rightButtonIsAlreadyPrimary != 0)
        {
            SwapMouseButton(0);  // Make the left mousebutton primary
        }
    }
}
```

And compile it to swapmouse.exe with this command:

```
"%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc" swapmouse.cs
```

Now you may create a folder called C:\Program Files\swapmouse and copy the swapmouse.exe to the newly created folder.

Now create a shortcut for this swapmouse.exe file on your desktop.

Under the property of the shortcut file, add a shortcut key, in this case, I used "Ctrl + Alt + S" and apply.

**Now everytime you press "Ctrl + Alt + S" the mouse button will be swapped.**

**There is no dependency on the mouse to change the mouse button anymore.**

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

A few good Autohotkey suggestions here, but this one swaps the buttons in Windows directly and gives a popup notification.

It's a copy of the mouseswap Autoit script mentioned by mica.

```
#a::
if button = 0
    {
    DllCall("SwapMouseButton", "int", 1)
    button = 1
    SplashTextOn, 120, 30, Mouse Button, Left handed
    Sleep 600
    SplashTextOff
    }
else
    {
    DllCall("SwapMouseButton", "int", 0)
    button = 0
    SplashTextOn, 120, 30, Mouse Button, Right handed
    Sleep 600
    SplashTextOff
    }
return
```

A terser alternative without the popup:

```
Swapped := DllCall("SwapMouseButton", Int, 0)
if Swapped = 0
 DllCall("SwapMouseButton", Int, 1)
```